# Cannot capture system audio output with Electron desktopcapturer in Ubuntu

Tags: audio, electron, capture

I want to capture OS system audio output with Electron desktopcapturer, it works well in Windows as following:

```
        constraints = {
        // audio: false,
        audio: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
            }
        },
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
                //maxFrameRate: 15
            },
        }
```

then, I use: 
`navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, function(dstream) {...`

However, in Ubuntu, it always shows "could not start audio source". Can anyone tell me how to do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Because of a patch merged in Chromium, it's not possible to access system audio without much low-level tinkering. [Here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10515) is an issue raised on Electron's github page but is left un-resolved since 6yrs. Quoting a reply from the issue, that seems to be of little hope:

> I was searching through the Chromium issue tracker, and found this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1143761&q=linux%20streaming&can=2
> This may be worth keeping an eye on, since it seems related to this issue. It's possible that this issue may see resolution when the Chromium team starts pushing fixes.

[Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/4519c32f528e079f25cb2afc594ecf625f943782) is the pulseaudio patch submitted to chromium, which is the root cause of this issue. **Comming to a potential solution you can revert back before this commit and audio capture should work fine then. But, I haven't tried out this solution.** Let me know if someone manages to fix this, or try this.

Comment: thanks for your comments. It seems that we have no choice now.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving my answer here for the record, it may or may not work for you. I ran into this error while testing my Electron app, while being in a Google Meet at the same time (i.e. Chrome had a lock on my microphone). The error stopped happening once I ended the Meet.